# Email headers modifications/removing in qmail

Tags: security, email, header, qmail

Is it any way to remove "Received:" header in qmail?

I do not want my recepient to know from where I did send my message.

Comment: This is a good question for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Personally I like to know where my spam came from.

Answer (score 0):

The Received: header is inserted by the recipient's system, so no, what you're asking is not possible.

Comment: I think that "Received:" header is generated by SMTP server, not client.

Comment: @Andrey: When `yourhost` initiates an outgoing SMTP session to `recipienthost` to deliver your message, it is `recipienthost` that inserts the `Received:` header.  And in that context, `yourhost` is the client and `recipienthost` is the server, so yes, that header is generated on the server side.  But you only have control over the client, `yourhost`.

Comment: Maybe we missunderstood each other. Lets describe how I do test.
Some of my customers and I want to be incognito. I have control under my PC and my Qmail email server. I made a test. I want to send an email to my third emailbox. I'm connecting with my email program to my SMTP server and send a mail. I want my email server NOT TO ADD this header. maybe change it, maybe do something else.
If server just forward my message, why he is not able change it? I think he is...

Comment: BTW, there is a solution for Postfix here: http://www.posluns.com/guides/hedrem.html